# Llimitation while converting big json into csv in Power Query Editor

Tags: json, csv, powerquery

I am trying to import a 150 MB JSON file into CSV. But all the rows have different number of keys. Issue is that excel find the metadata only based on the first 1000 rows and there are chances that new keys/ columns will be present after the first 1000 rows. Excel says: "Limit of 1000 scanned rows reached"

How do I handle this?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a real example when PQ do not read your Json correctly? I do not think that there could be an error, never seen it. But anyway, of you have a schema for your json, you could explain it to the Power Query - use it as the sample for creating a parsing function, then pass a real JSON to this function

Comment: Yes, I have a JSONL file with around 44000 json records and each JSON record has different structure (i.e. say 1001st JSON record has a new key which is not present in the first 1000 JSONs). In this case, what I understand is, PQ parses first 1000 records and defines the columns structure for the excel sheet. So what is happening is, once I load the data the result is missing the new JSON key which is present in the 100 1st JSON. I shall add a screenshot to the question above for reference.

Comment: Reason why I can't define the JSON schema is because, each JSON in my jSONL file can be different. There are certain JSON record with 2000 keys, whereas some maybe just a subset of that.

Comment: Your objective is to add a Filter step?

Comment: I want that entire json to be imported into excel. I have confirmed that this is a bug with excel PQ. Suppose I have a JSON file with 1100 rows of {"key1":"va11","key2":"val2"} and then 1101 row be {"key1":"va11","key2":"val2","key3":"val3"}, then the final imported data in excel will not have key3 column. But if the same row with additional column is inserted as the 500th row, then everything will be normal. Issue is, PQ doesnt read the metadata for 1000+ rows.

Answer (score 2):

Try to solve the problem in several steps -

1. Cut head of 0 rows and tail after 1k rows `Table.FirstN`/`Table.Skip`/`Table.LastN`/`Table.RemoveLastN`
2. Then filter your rows
3. Turn back to p.1 (or insert new step) and change head cut to 1k and tail to 2k
4. Repeat

[image]

After all delete head and tail cuts and leave only Filter steps. It's not optimal, but works